# How do I create new pandas dataframe by grouping multiple variables?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting, pandas-groupby

I am having tremendous difficulty getting my data sorted. I'm at the point where I could have manually created a new .csv file in the time I have spent trying to figure this out, but I need to do this through code. I have a large dataset of baseball salaries by player going back 150 years.
[This is what my dataset looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HclTq.png).

I want to create a new dataframe that adds the individual player salaries for a given team for a given year, organized by team and by year. Using the following technique I have come up with this: `team_salaries_groupby_team = salaries.groupby(['teamID','yearID']).agg({'salary' : ['sum']})`, which outputs this: [my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRrhj.png). On screen it looks sort of like what I want, but I want a dataframe with three columns (plus an index on the left). I can't really do the sort of analysis I want to do with this output.

Lastly, I have also tried this method: `new_column = salaries['teamID'] + salaries['yearID'].astype(str) salaries['teamyear'] = new_column salaries teamyear = salaries.groupby(['teamyear']).agg({'salary' : ['sum']}) print(teamyear)`. [Another output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OkVls.png) It adds the individual player salaries per team for a given year, but now I don't know how to separate the year and put it into its own column. Help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to `reset_index()`

Here is sample code :

```
salaries = pd.DataFrame(columns=['yearID','teamID','igID','playerID','salary'])

salaries=salaries.append({'yearID':1985,'teamID':'ATL','igID':'NL','playerID':'A','salary':10000},ignore_index=True)
salaries=salaries.append({'yearID':1985,'teamID':'ATL','igID':'NL','playerID':'B','salary':20000},ignore_index=True)
salaries=salaries.append({'yearID':1985,'teamID':'ATL','igID':'NL','playerID':'A','salary':10000},ignore_index=True)
salaries=salaries.append({'yearID':1985,'teamID':'ATL','igID':'NL','playerID':'C','salary':5000},ignore_index=True)
salaries=salaries.append({'yearID':1985,'teamID':'ATL','igID':'NL','playerID':'B','salary':20000},ignore_index=True)

salaries=salaries.append({'yearID':2016,'teamID':'ATL','igID':'NL','playerID':'A','salary':100000},ignore_index=True)
salaries=salaries.append({'yearID':2016,'teamID':'ATL','igID':'NL','playerID':'B','salary':200000},ignore_index=True)
salaries=salaries.append({'yearID':2016,'teamID':'ATL','igID':'NL','playerID':'C','salary':50000},ignore_index=True)
salaries=salaries.append({'yearID':2016,'teamID':'ATL','igID':'NL','playerID':'A','salary':100000},ignore_index=True)
salaries=salaries.append({'yearID':2016,'teamID':'ATL','igID':'NL','playerID':'B','salary':200000},ignore_index=True)
```

After that , `groupby` and `reset_index`

```
sample_df = salaries.groupby(['teamID', 'yearID']).salary.sum().reset_index()
```

[image: Output]

Is this what you are looking for ?

Comment: Yeah, I'm looking to build a dataframe just like that, but with the total salary for the team, added from each player for that team in that year. It looks like you're making it manually though, row by row. I have several thousand rows of data to work with though. Have any ideas to run a line of code to pull every row at the selected columns at the same time? I've been messing around with `.loc` to try to do this. 
`salaries = salaries.append({'yearID':salaries.loc[0], 'teamID':salaries.loc[2], 'salary':salaries.loc[4]}, ignore_index = True)`

This throws an error though.

Comment: @redleg_64 : 

Please ignore the `append` part that is just to create a dummy dataframe.

`sample_df = salaries.groupby(['teamID', 'yearID']).salary.sum().reset_index() ` --> this part is I believe what you are looking for. Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @redleg_64 : I assumed you already have the dataframe . If not , then you may need to use `join` or `merge` of pandas.

Comment: Thank you so much @DukeLover for helping me get this figured out. It can be frustrating to know WHAT you want to do to your data, but to not be able to do it through code. #imarookie